# Python unittest: Reporting Exception as Failure

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to check for an exception in Python unittest, with the following requirements:

- Needs to be reported as a failure, NOT an error
- Must not swallow the original exception

I've seen lots of solutions of the form:

```
try:
    something()
except:
    self.fail("It failed")
```

Unfortunately these solutions swallow the original exception.  Any way to retain the original exception?

I ended up using a variant of Pierre GM's answer:

```
try:
   something()
except:
    self.fail("Failed with %s" % traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you could use the context of a generic exception:

```
except Exception, error:
    self.fail("Failed with %s" % error)
```

You can also retrieve the information relative to the exception through [`sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)

```
try:
    1./0
except:
    (etype, evalue, etrace) = sys.exc_info()
    self.fail("Failed with %s" % evalue)
```

The tuple `(etype, evalue, etrace)` is here `(<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('float division',), <traceback object at 0x7f6f2c02fa70>)`