# When maintaining a test suite, should all 'errors' eventually become 'failures'?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm a user of python unittest, but this crosses all languages.

Senario: I have uncovered a defect in 'functionBeingTested'.
The defect is that on valid input the code will crash (throw an exception)

When writing a test case, I can very simply:

```
def testThis(self):
    self.assertEqual( functionBeingTested("valid input"), "expected output")
```

In TDD terminology, this would expect to 'Fail', but instead, it will raise an exception, and you get an 'error':

```
 Ran 1 tests with 0 failures and 1 errors
```

One would assume you would want:

```
 Ran 1 tests with 1 failures and 0 errors
```

There are solutions to this [Python unittest: Reporting Exception as Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510412/python-unittest-reporting-exception-as-failure)

And a similar discussion here: [pass a unit test if an exception isn't thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181555/pass-a-unit-test-if-an-exception-isnt-thrown)

But that is not the question.

The question is "Best Practices of Maintaining Test Suites"

Is it philosophically acceptable to write an 'Erroring test case' [if there is such a thing]  in pure test driven development, or should this unittest be written to catch the exception and raise an assertion error to demonstrate a 'failure' instead of an 'error'.

Some more reading that failed to shed light on this question:
http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/html/ch5#Ref1.1.2
"IEEE Standard Glossary of Software Engineering Terminology" (google it)

And look at the edit between Python 2 and Python 3 unittest documentation:
 http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code
 http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code

Seems that in Python 3 this phrase was omitted:

> [error] helps you identify where the problem is: failures are caused
>   by incorrect results - a 5 where you expected a 6. Errors are caused
>   by incorrect code - e.g., a TypeError caused by an incorrect function
>   call.

---

Other titles for this question are being considered:
 "Why is there a 'failure' and 'error' case from unit tests?"
   or
 "What's the philosophical difference between a 'failure' and an 'error'
   or
 "In TDD, should all "failing tests" be written to throw 'failures' or are 'errors' acceptable"

Still trying to pin down exactly what I'm asking here, without getting simple answers like "One is an Assertion Error and the other is not", which I will gladly downvote.

Comment: This can't be just splitting hairs, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception is one way to indicate failure.  It means that one of the preconditions of the test was not met.  Asking "did this call fail to throw an exception" is not generally interesting -- it is a question we would otherwise have to ask of all code.

The fact that a bug of "this nominally valid input causes an exception to be thrown" was discovered indicates that there was a bug in the test suite -- some classes of inputs were not being covered.  Classes of input that cause exceptions to be thrown generally need slightly specialized rules about what the expected output should be, so there is almost always documentary value in phrasing the test for the newly-uncovered bug as a fix for the lack-of-coverage bug.

Which is a long-winded way of saying that yes, the test you wrote tests two things.  But one of the things it tests is a thing that we should not test for explicitly, because it is not interesting.  Boring tests are bad tests.

Comment: I like "boring tests are bad tests", and understand.  I don't like writing tests that catch exceptions, unless I'm specifically looking for a very specific exception.

Upvoted because "Throwing an exception is one way to indicate failure"

But does this mean that "total failures of code being tested" is simply "Errors + Failures"?  Why even distinguish between them if that's the case?  I am still leaning towards Failure = Tested Code Is Broken and Error = Test Framework is broken, but I don't know if this is really true.

Comment: @flipmcf It is quite reasonable to look at exceptions as simply oddly-reported failures.  There are differences in the way we think about them and in what they mean about which part of the system we are building is breaking -- exceptions tend to indicate an erroneous assumption -- but I don't construe the difference as fundamental.